# How can I programmatically extract data from a database?

Tags: database

I am working with a database that takes extremely long to download any data. There is a user interface where I enter fields like date range, specify the fields I want to extract eg. name of person etc. then I click submit and it takes many hours to return any data.

Is there any way of accessing the data directly/more quickly that anyone can advise of using; anything available in python, R, sql - any way to do it at all really?

Comment: Depends on your database. But normally, sure. What kind of database do you have?

Comment: Okay, I can find that out. It is a company database and I don't know what is behind the user interface i.e. how it is built.

Comment: Perhaps advise me on the steps I would need to take to be able to do this.

Comment: 1. Find out what software "a database" actually is.